# Is there a way to not display empty TreeCells in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, treeview

My TreeView is displayed even though there are no TreeItems in it. Is there any way to not display the TreeCells before they actually have a corresponding TreeItem to display?

**This is how it looks without any items:**

[image: Only root]

**This is how it looks when one item is added to the root:**

[image: Tree with one item]

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can not prevent empty `TreeCell`s being added to the `TreeView`, but if all you care about is appearance, you can define different style for empty cells. Empty cells have the `:empty` pseudo class, which you can use in your CSS:

```
.tree-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but actually I didn't even need the PseudoClass :P Empty was already an option. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AnagramOfJoans What do you mean by "Empty was already an option"?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but all I needed to solve my problem was to write those three lines of css code, just exchanging white with transparent. Now it looks empty when it is empty, which was what I wanted :)

Comment: Right, I overlooked the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell) saying that all `Cell`s have the `empty` pseudo class already. I updated the answer.